# Return Authors by latest published book + Authors with no published books

Tags: sql

I have two tables :

•Table 1: `Books`
•Table 2: `Authors`

I have the following query:(This query returns all authors with book title and date published)

```
SELECT Authors.AuthorName, Books.BookTitle, Books.DatePublished, Books.Author
FROM Authors LEFT OUTER JOIN Books ON Authors.AuthorID = Books.Author
```

**Problem:!!**

I would like to return all Authors(Both who have books published . and those that dont have books published.

Condition (The authors that do have books. return only the latest published book)

*I am able to get latest published book with the below query:*

```
SELECT a.*    
FROM [Books] a left outer join Books b on a.Author = b.author and 
a.DatePublished < b.DatePublished where b.ISDN  is null
```

**Question: How can i incorporate both these queries to return ALL the
   authors + authors with latest published book ?**

Comment: Please add some sample data and expected output to understand your question easily. Mention database like MS Sql server, Oracle, MySql etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    AuthorName, 
    BookTitle, 
    DatePublished, 
    Author 
FROM(
    SELECT 
        Authors.AuthorName, 
        Books.BookTitle, 
        Books.DatePublished, 
        Books.Author, 
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Authors.AuthorID order by DatePublished desc) Rnum
    FROM Authors LEFT OUTER JOIN Books ON Authors.AuthorID = Books.Author
)x WHERE Rnum=1
```

Comment: I used this query however it returns duplicates

Comment: Please check by adding a distinct in outer select, I have updated result.

Comment: the distinct still returns duplicates

Comment: Which column is repeated?

Comment: AuthorID AuthorName ISDN BookTitle
1        Bob         899  BobMansion
1        Bob         899  BobMAnsion